# PhantomData and mutable reference give a "does not live long enough" error

Tags: types, reference, rust

I am trying to create a type that is sending and receiving data over the network and serializing/deserializing the bytes into a declared type. For this, I have been using the `PhantomData` type in `std`. However, I recently came on a situation where I wanted to make my method take a `&mut self` parameter and rustc would not compile it. In the code below, everything works when there is no mutable reference, but by adding the mutable reference I get `<anon>:24:18: 24:21 error: vec does not live long enough`.

I also tried using a `PhantomData<*const T>` type so as not to imply ownership, but that did not work as well. Getting rid of the PhantomData from the struct does allow the code to compile however.

```
use std::io;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
struct Test<T> {
    data: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Test<T> {
    fn test(&mut self, _t: &T) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
      Ok(())
    }
}

//impl<T> Test<T> {
//    fn test(&self, _t: &T) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
//      Ok(())
//    }
//}

fn main() {
    let test = Test {
        data: PhantomData,
    };
    let vec = vec![1u8];
    let slice = &vec[..];
    let _res = test.test(&slice);
}
```

http://is.gd/okj55K

I do not want to move the creation of the `vec` before the `test`. Imagine `test` as a socket bound at the beginning of a process and `vec` as some ephemeral data that is being passed through it.
Any insight would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**
I would like to know why this works with `&self` and not with `&mut self`. I am looking to understand exactly what is occurring here so that I can decide what my next steps should be. Getting this specific code working is great but secondary to an informative explanation of what the `rustc` compiler is thinking.

Comment: `&vec[..]` should be written as just `&vec` nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the corrected code:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1u8];
    let mut test = Test {
        data: PhantomData,
    };
    let slice = &vec[..];
    let _res = test.test(&slice);
}
```

I moved the `vec` creation first.
Then the `test` variable must be mutable, because the `test` method requires so.

**Edit after the comment**

The problem with your code is that the generic type `T` used in the `Test` type is inferred when you call the `test` method the first time. In this case that type is a slice with its own lifetime. In fact a slice is a borrow so it has also its own lifetime.
In your example that lifetime is shorter than the `test` variable lifetime so you have the problem.

A possible solution is to use the `Vec` as type this way:

```
let mut test = Test {
    data: PhantomData,
};
let vec = vec![1u8];
let _res = test.test(&vec);
```

Comment: Right, that would make this code work, but I do not want to have to create the Vec before creating the `Test` struct. I should have been more explicit about that. Imagine the `Test` struct as a socket that is created at the beginning of the process and the `vec` as ephemeral data that is being passed through it.

Comment: @crhino I added another solution.

Comment: That works if I use `Vec<u8>`, but I would also like to support the use of `&[u8]` as well. I still unsure as to why the slice needs to have a longer lifetime then the `test` variable. My understanding is that the slice need only outlive the call to `test.test(&slice)`. That is what I am trying to accomplish at any rate.

Comment: @crhino The problem is that the inferred Test type get the slice type as T together with its lifetime. This is because the slice is a borrow. You can find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371255/why-do-slices-in-a-structure-require-a-lifetime-but-not-vectors

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks for being patient with me!